How to use yup async validation with formik and React and avoid to see first required validation
I have React application with formik and yup for building forms.
I need create form with list of inputs, with codes and there must be async validations for API, which will confirm if the code exists.
I tried following form:
import { Formik, Field, FieldArray, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

interface BarcodeFormValues {
  barcodes: { code: string }[];
}

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  barcodes: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      code: Yup.string()
        .required("Barcode is required")
        .test("checkBarcodeExists", "Barcode does not exist", async (value) => {
          if (!value) return false;

          // add delay
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

          // fake it, that validations failed
          return false;
        }),
    })
  ),
});

const initialValues: BarcodeFormValues = {
  barcodes: [{ code: "" }],
};

const BarcodeForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      validateOnChange={true}
      validateOnBlur={false}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log("Submitted values:", values);
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray name="barcodes">
            {({ remove, push }) => (
              <div>
                {values.barcodes.length > 0 &&
                  values.barcodes.map((barcode, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Field
                        name={`barcodes.${index}.code`}
                        placeholder="Enter barcode"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name={`barcodes.${index}.code`}
                        component="div"
                      />
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                <button type="button" onClick={() => push({ code: "" })}>
                  Add New
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </FieldArray>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default BarcodeForm;


The issue is, that if you add more inputs and you try type something inside input, you can see first error message - "Barcode is required" - but you put something there, so I do not want to see this message, and then after some time you will see result of async validation.
How is it possible to adjust my code to get rid of to see first this "Required error message" and display only this message in case that input is really empty.
Here is example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/x6fxzr

Here what I would do is store the error for each field separately, then add event listener on each input on change with a request that is being throttled - only fires if the state has not changed for over 1 second (i.e.) Then change the border color of the input to red and add the error under it. This is relatively simple to do.

Can you modify codesandbox with your idea?

In order to successfully achieve this we must customize our error. So remove the .required and do it the error yourself using ctx.
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  barcodes: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      code: Yup.string()
        //.required("Barcode is required") Remove
        .test(
        "checkBarcodeExists",
        "Barcode does not exist",
        async (value, ctx) => {
          if (!value) // Solution!!
            return ctx.createError({ message: "Barcode is required" });

          // add delay
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

          // fake it, that validations failed
          return false;
        }
      ),
    })
  ),
});

Edit: Extending the solution as you commented. You can use Composition and Reuse to reuse other validations you already have. Example:
const stringBoundsSchema = Yup.string().min(2).max(10).defined();
...
// inside .test
            if (!stringBoundsSchema.isValid(value))
              return ctx.createError({ message: "Out of bounds" });


Edit²: If you want to keep the message from the other schema you have to access them like this:
          const stringBoundsSchemaResult = await stringBoundsSchema
            .validate(value)
            .then(() => false)
            .catch((e) => e.errors.join(", "));
          if (stringBoundsSchemaResult)
            return ctx.createError({ message: stringBoundsSchemaResult });


if you want to have a of max one message pass a option param to validate like: .validate(value, { abortEarly: true });


In our scenario we have multiple chain of validations like, required(), min(), max(). we need to solve in the way with these extension methods. Is it possible to somehow call this min, max, required inside test method as well? via yup functions?

@Jenan In order for it to behave exactly like you described i can only imagine putting it all inside .test.

You can consider migrating to zod for validation. The chaining works more as expected.

@Jenan just edited the answer with a alternative for your chain.

is it possible to get error message from the stringBoundsSchema and use it inside test method? this would be great solution for me, because { message: "Out of bounds" } is not clear, I need know what rule is not correct.

For example - Barcode is required or Min value is 2. etc.

@Jenan Yes you can. Just edited with a solution for that.

I tested this approach and if stringBoundsSchemaResult is false and it does to validate via async method, this takes 2 seconds than previous error message disappears. Have you tried your solution in codesandbox? I simulate it like this: try hit first sync validation and then you receive error message and than if you want to validate async api call, here via setTimeout, previous message is still there. Please, try add more items in array. thanks for you effort! Edit: Would be nice to somehow clear previous error before.

@Jenan now it looks like it'd need to use the errors prop of Formik (probably doing the validation all custom with the validate prop and having a external state)..... I do strongly suggest you migrate to hook-form + zod. This combination handles this scenario perfectly with no hacking. Anyway, Good luck!!
